# Insert foreign html code int document using php

Tags: php, html

I wonder how can I insert an html document into another one using php. E.g.:

`header.html`

```
<div id="header">Hey this is header</div>
```

`index.php`

```
<body>
<? get_document('header.html'); ?>
...
```

I could use ajax for that but I dont want my web site to depend on js. Thank you!

Comment: George Cumming's answer is best. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `include`/`require`.  That can be done on any file, not just PHP files.

You could also do `echo file_get_contents('header.html');` but `include` makes more sense in this case.

Comment: function file_get_contents is great solution cuz I can put it in other function so it gives me good level of incapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.include.php) to include one document in another:

```
<body>
<?php include('header.html'); ?>
...
```

If you want execution to fail if the file is not present, use [`require()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.require.php):

```
<body>
<?php require('header.html'); ?>
...
```

Be aware that [short-open tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) (`<?`) do not work on all servers and are disabled by default in new version of PHP. For this reason, it is best to use the full-open tag: `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
...
<body>
<?php
      include("header.html");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you want to store it in variable and use later as you wish

```
   ob_start();
   include("header.html");
   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();


   echo $content;
```